# Подходит ли фреймворк phaser для разработки профессиональной 2d игры?

Tags: javascript, html5, разработка-игр, phaser-framework

Появилось желание написать 2d игру для загрузки в google play и apple store(с продвижением, в дальнейшем для заработка денег). По скольку хорошо знаю JS решил писать на нем, взгляд упал на фреймворк phaser. И теперь встал вопрос можно ли на нем написать профессиональную игру которая будет хорошо отрабатывать на моб. устройствах и показывать нормальную продуктивность? Возможно есть другие более лучшие фреймворки или библиотеки?Или не стоит вообще браться за написания этого на JS? У кого есть возможность по скидывайте пожалуйста годные примеры 2d игр под моб. устройства на JS.

Comment: ИМХО, но лучше всего в текущее время для разработки игр подходит движок Unity или Unreal. Unity поддерживает JS.

Comment: @Любитель, в unity не js а unityScript, и его вроде бы уже не поддерживают, только C#

Comment: 1) Вряд ли вы "хорошо" знаете js. 2) Думать о деньгах, когда вы даже не знаете на чем писать...далеко пойдете. 3) Загуглите популярные движки, если вы "хорошо" знаете js, вам не составит проблемы опробовать несколько движков и выбрать себе по душе, если вы не собираетесь писать ГТА5 на телефон, координально при выборе движка ничего не изменится, выбирать нужно то, с чем вам приятнее работать.
p.s Обычно на сайте движка уже указаны примеры игр реализованные с помощью него.